# Matrices and prime numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, finite-fields

> Let $ p $ be a prime number and \begin{align} K=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ 
>  c& d \end{pmatrix} \mid a,b,c,d \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,p-1 \right\}, \right. & a+d \equiv 1 \!\!\!\! \pmod p, \\
> & ad-bc \equiv 0 \!\!\!\! \pmod p \left.\vphantom{\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ 
>  c& d \end{pmatrix}} \right\}. \end{align}
>   Determine $\operatorname{card}(K) $.

I have taken some particular cases: $ p=2,3,5 \text{ or } 7 $ and I've deduced that $\operatorname{card}(K)=p(p+1) $, but I can't extend the solution to the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to count them.  Note that any such matrix can be built by one of the two following methods:

**Method 1:**

1. Select $a \in \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$
2. Select a non-zero value for $b$
3. Solve for $d = 1 - a$, $c = \frac{ad}{b}$

Note that there are $p(p-1)$ matrices that we get from this method.

**Method 2:**

1. Set $b = 0$
2. $c$ may be freely chosen
3. Either set $a = 0$ and $d = 1$, or $a = 1$ and $d = 0$

There are exactly $2p$ matrices that we get from this method.

---

In total, we thus have $p(p-1) + 2p = p(p+1)$ such matrices.

Comment: Why is $ d=1-a $ and not $ p+1-a $ ?

Comment: I really meant that $d \equiv 1 - a \pmod{p} $, which is the same as $d = p+1 - a$.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean by $c = \frac{ad}{b}$, then?